# Google Analytics Web

Tags: google-analytics

Recently i found out there is someone sharing that the had get a news and email from google and its about "Google are going to sunset the Google Analytics Mobile Apps"
We believe slowly it will replace by Firebase Analytics.

However, would like to know is it the google analytics Web will be affected as well?
Currently we are using Google Analytics Web for traffic track on the company website.
is it compulsory for us to migrate our website tracking from Google Analytics to Firebase Analytics?

Appreciate if anyone could advice and share some idea on these issue.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do anything, the sunset only affects GA for apps.